# What is the equivalent of YUI 3's Y.Array() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, yui

What is the equivalent of YUI 3's Y.Array in jQuery?

Y.Array() takes array like inputs and converts them into array. More info at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/yui-array.js.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you need http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

Comment: Yeah this is what I needed. Not sure how I missed it when I looked into the docs.